# Enthought Canopy on OSX "Could not connect to authentication server"

Tags: macos, authentication, enthought, canopy

After what seemed like a successful renewing of an academic license of Enthought Canopy 1.4.0 installed on OS10.9.2 executing any code would immediately return a crash report that said among other things:

*User not logged in: Authentication failed: Authentication error: UNAUTHORIZED.*

I did a complete clean re-install and now code runs but starting package manager returns an error:

*Could not connect to authentication server. Reason: UNAUTHORIZED
Could not connect to Canopy server.
Please check your network connection.
Package manager will not be able to update or install new packages.
If you are behind a proxy firewall, please check your proxy settings in the Preferences dialog*

My network connection seems to be fine and I have moved to another location to get on a completely different network and get the same result and am not aware of any proxy firewall on either network.

Comment: This seems like a question for Enthought Tech Support.

Comment: Yes. Support request received and queued. (This is a free subscription.)